# MDB Angular's datepicker gives me an error in web console

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I have 2 MDB modal components and in both modal components I have 2 datepickers in each modal.
In my first modal, datepicker works perfect, but in my second modal, datepicker doesn't work. As soon as si click on calendar icon it displays only half of the datepicker and gives me error in my web console.

*Please, feel free to tell me if you need any more information.*

```
  <label mdbLabel for="manufacturingDate" class="form-label">Date</label>
  <mdb-form-control>
    <input
      mdbInput
      [mdbDatepicker]="datepicker3"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      id="manufacturingDate"
      name="manufacturingDate"
      [(ngModel)]="manufacturingDate"
    />
    <mdb-datepicker-toggle
      [mdbDatepicker]="datepicker3"
    ></mdb-datepicker-toggle>
    <mdb-datepicker
      #datepicker3
      [options]="translationOptions"
    ></mdb-datepicker>
  </mdb-form-control>
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks to everyone for help!

Comment: Can you please tell me what value is in manufacturingDate this variable?

Comment: The value is the date, fetched from API (it is in edit component, but if i make value empty it works. So problem is here)

Comment: Yes so the problem was in your value